# Clear DNS cache in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, laravel-vapor

How to clear the DNS cache of an instance in AWS Lambda?

Context:
We backup the database to an external S3 provider. It has worked for few years now.
Recently they did a maintenance and added some proxies servers and renewed their SSL certificates (20 april) and since then (5 days later) I'm still getting the error:

> Copying zip failed because: Could not connect to disk s3-infomaniak
> because: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could
> not resolve host: s3.swiss-backup02.infomaniak.com (see
> https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for
> https://s3.swiss-backup02.infomaniak.com/default?list-type=2&prefix=database-backup%2F&delimiter=%2F

We suppose that the DNS cache is still pointing to the old destination.

- The website is managed with Laravel vapor: https://vapor.laravel.com
- I confirm the S3 is resolvable from our AWS EC2 and from my machine
- The backups works from the EC2 and from my machine
- With or without the NAT, it doesn't change anything
- Redeploying didn't change anything

Comment: "Could not resolve host" if it's a DNS cache, it's a negative cache. https://serverfault.com/questions/426807/how-long-does-negative-dns-caching-typically-last  explains how that's controlled.  I see a value of 60 (seconds) in the SOA record for the host in question.  I don't think it's DNS caching that's causing this.

Comment: I don't have any other idea. It only happens from our AWS lambdas (with and without NAT). I works successfully when running from a VPC or locally.

Comment: Are the lambdas not running in the same VPC that works?

Comment: @erik258 Sorry for the delay, I was looking with AWS support. It seems the issue is either an issue with the vapor's Dockerfile nor infomaniak new proxies / servers. By creating a new lambda, I'm able to reach the domain from the PHP native runtime with cURL, but as soon I switch to vapor's Dockerfile, I'm not able to reach the domain with cURL. At this point I think it's something I can't do anything with, but still looking with Infomaniak support. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue, and it was not the cache.

1. I could replicate the issue by creating a sub domain with 24 A records (the same amount of records that have been added to s3.swiss-backup02.infomaniak.com)
2. Then I could still replicate the issue by (and only by) using an Alpine based image on lambda.

Apparently, Alpine seems to have some DNS issues on Kubernetes cluster due to the usage of musl-libc instead of g-libc<sup>1</sup>. Having a "large" DNS answer seems to be the case with lambda.

Since Laravel vapor is using Alpine based image for their Dockerfiles<sup>2</sup> *(You're not concerned if you use native runtimes)*
I did a fork<sup>3</sup> of their image with `php:8.2-fpm-buster` and now the URL is reachable.

---

<sup>1</sup> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65593511/8068675
<sup>2</sup> https://github.com/laravel/vapor-dockerfiles/blob/master/php82.Dockerfile
<sup>3</sup> https://github.com/melba-ch/vapor-dockerfiles-buster